# MarkLogic Server on AWS

Tags: marklogic

Could anyone give me a precise explanation about
any restriction for using ML marketplace edition vs BYOL?
e.g. Using Optional features, topology restriction, support etc..

I still cannot find a clear definition in the document,
will be helpful if anyone can point where I can found those information
officially on the MarkLogic web.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Consider posting your question on the MarkLogic General Developers Mailing list, details can be found here: http://developer.marklogic.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MarkLogic Essential Enterprise Edition for AWS Marketplace includes the same features as MarkLogic Essential Enterprise - Multi-Model, ACID, Certified Security, Clustering, HA, DR, etc.  There are no limitations around topology.  Enterprise Support is included with annual subscriptions.
This information is presented on the AWS Marketplace site: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B072Z6YK6K?qid=1518802554564&sr=0-2&ref_=srh_res_product_title

While this edition does not have support for optional features, those are available with BYOL. Consult the documentation for more detail information about use of the features. You may find that the marketplace edition meets your needs.  HA, DR, SQL, Bitemporal Queries, Partitions, Federation, Encryption (with embedded wallet), Element Level Security, most Geospatial queries, Indexing Semantic triples for query with Optic + SQL, and many, many other features are included in this edition.

Features requiring optional licenses are listed at the beginning of the Guide documents. For example, at the beginning of the Security Guide:
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/intro

Role base security, Element Level Security, use of Encryption without KMS, and all the other rich security features in MarkLogic do not require the Advanced Security option and therefore are part of the Marketplace edition license.

"Some MarkLogic Server security features require an Advanced Security License in addition to the regular license. The Advanced Security License option is required when using:

- Compartment Security
- Redaction
- An external Key Management System
  (KMS) or keystore with encryption at rest"

(I am a MarkLogic employee)